# Adding Arduino library to Atmel Studio 7 AVR C++ project - missing Arduino.h

Tags: c++, arduino, avr

I've opened an AVR C++ project in Atmel Studio. I want to use an Ardunio library to drive a TFT screen. After adding the library I've noticed the header file calls for SPI.H and according to the function calls it is the Arduino library. I have added the SPI library using right click -> add Arduino library and it added SPI.h and SPI.cpp. SPI.h in including Arduino.h which it not found.

Are there additional steps in adding an Arduino library? The file itself is not found in the Arduino folder BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino.h is found in the Arduino core.  On my installation it is at

XXX/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino

where XXX is the folder where Arduino was installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Arduino to its default location, it will be located in this folder:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino

Comment: I have added the said folder to the compiler search folders, however once it found the Arduino.h file it needs a whole bunch of other header files. Isn't there a simple way to set the Arduino folder and all sub-folders in the seach folders?